# Getting sproutcore application files to use them in a native app via Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: cross-platform, titanium, sproutcore, offlineapps

I would like build a app using sproucore framework, but i also want to integrate it with Titanium to have some desktop capability like file system, packaging, offline working etc...

I know that with sproutcore 2 this would be pretty easy since it allows to use the framework like a normal javascript library. But the project is still in beta and the docs are patchy at most (I consider patchy even the 1.x docs, actually).

So, I want to ask, which would be the best way to go to integrate sproutcore and Titanium API?

Answer (score 0):

Titanium's main mission is to use JavaScript to build native apps, not to provide a OS-access layer for web apps. It would be hard to mix native and SproutCore UI elements.

That being said, here's some information that might help you:
Titanium has reversed it's application model starting with version 1.0:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/71/what-happened-to-html--css

The main app doesn't run in a web view anymore, instead it runs directly in JavaScriptCore and creates only native UI elements. One of the native UI elements is a web view
(http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.WebView-object)
and it's possible to make that full screen and run your SproutCore app inside of the web view. From there, you can call out to Titanium to call Titanium methods for file system access and the like.

Also, if you only target the desktop, you could even access the JavaScript context object of a webview and use it directly in JavaScriptCore.

- Johannes